# Is there other way I can choose not to sort x-label

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I know one way to not sort the x-label is using `set_xticklabels`, but I am wondering if there is another method to solve the problem. I mean, how can I not sort the x-label except using `set_xticklabels`?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import random
    url="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"
    df = pd.read_csv(url,header=None,names=['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num', 'marital-status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'capital-gain', 'capital-loss', 'hours-per-week','native-country', 'result'])

    fnlwgt=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.iloc[i,2]<=50000:
            fnlwgt[0]+=1
        elif df.iloc[i,2]<=100000:
            fnlwgt[1]+=1
        elif df.iloc[i,2]<=150000:
            fnlwgt[2]+=1
        elif df.iloc[i,2]<=200000:
            fnlwgt[3]+=1
        elif df.iloc[i,2]<=250000:
            fnlwgt[4]+=1
        elif df.iloc[i,2]<=300000:
            fnlwgt[5]+=1
        elif df.iloc[i,2]<=350000:
            fnlwgt[6]+=1
        elif df.iloc[i,2]<=400000:
            fnlwgt[7]+=1
        else:
            fnlwgt[8]+=1

    xs=['0~50k','50k~100k','100k~150k','150k~200k','200k~250k','250k~300k','300k~350k','350k~400k','400k~450k']

    plt.bar(xs,fnlwgt)
    plt.show()
```

Second question, When I use `set_xticklabels`, the figure showed a weird ratio. How can I solve it?

[image: 1]

I just change

```
    plt.bar(xs,fnlwgt)
    plt.show()
```

to

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
    ax1.bar(xs, fnlwgt)
    ax1.set_xticklabels(xs)
    plt.show()
```

No matter I zoomed in or opened to full screen, the figure still remained the same ratio. I know I can set the orientation but I just want to see whether I can get the same result without setting orientation.

Comment: Sorry, while you may have a valid question, this is not at all understandable. What exactly is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This is my first result: https://imgur.com/HhkK3AA.jpg  and I want  `50k~100k` be the second x-label, not the last x-label.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question, such that it becomes clear?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just edited the questions and the second question has got the answer. Thanks for your comment and sorry that the questions were not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change set the aspect ratio by changing the figure size. For example,

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax1.bar(xs, fnlwgt)
ax1.set_xticklabels(xs)
plt.show()
```

However, the aspect ratio is probably caused by the fact that you are creating 3 subplots (`ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)`) and only use one of the 3.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I set the wrong parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the tick labels readable by changing the aspect ratio of the figure itself or by moving the tick labels themselves? The aspect ratio can be configured to make the labels more readable by:

```
graph = plt.figure(figsize=(x, y))
```

While you can simply configure the positioning of the labels themselves by rotation or a number of other methods:

```
plt.xticklabels(rotation=90)
```